# Upload photo and tag friends using javascript sdk

Tags: javascript, facebook, facebook-graph-api, sdk

i m trying to post photo on users wall and tagging their friends in that photo. i have the permissions of the user of publish stream and photos. Now i m using the fb.api method to post on user wall and tag friends. my codes are working properly if i define the users id who will be tagged in that photo but i wanted to do that automatically and i tried these codes but this is not working because of some mistakes please anyone help me to fix the codes.

```
// Auto post picture of talent result
        FB.api('/me/photos', 'post', {
        access_token: response.authResponse.accessToken,
        url: 'http://guthrienewspage.files.wordpress.com/2013/10/talent.jpg',
        message: 'this is my new talent that i discovered', 
        tags: '[{tag_uid:12312,x:20,y:20},{tag_uid:34212,x:20,y:20},{tag_uid:123122132,x:20,y:20}]'
        }, function(response) {
        if (!response || response.error) {
        alert('Error occured');
        } else {
        alert('Post ID: ' + response.id);
        }
        });
```

the above code is working properply now i use the below code to retrieve the user friends id:

```
   FB.api('/me/friends', function(response) {
          if(response.data) {
           $.each(response.data,function(index,friend) {
        // friendidtag = {tag_uid: + friend.id + ,x:20,y:20},
        // alert(friend.name + ' has id:' + friend.id);
         var alltagsid = '{tag_uid: + friend.id + ,x:20,y:20},'; 
           });
          } else {
              alert("Error!");
              }
         });
```

and then using this var alltagsid in my first code like this:

```
// Auto post picture of talent result
    FB.api('/me/photos', 'post', {
    access_token: response.authResponse.accessToken,
    url: 'http://guthrienewspage.files.wordpress.com/2013/10/talent.jpg',
    message: 'this is my new talent that i discovered', 
    tags: '[alltagsid]'
    }, function(response) {
    if (!response || response.error) {
    alert('Error occured');
    } else {
    alert('Post ID: ' + response.id);
    }
    });
```

but this is not working plz help me out to fix this code. and please dont give me reference of api's just make this code fixed and post the answer if you can otherwise leave it.

Comment: Someone reply plz :((((((

Answer (score 0):

An Array Declaration In Javascript Is Like That. Check It

```
FB.api('/me/friends', function(response) {
      if(response.data) {
       $.each(response.data,function(index,friend) {
    // friendidtag = {tag_uid: + friend.id + ,x:20,y:20},
    // alert(friend.name + ' has id:' + friend.id);
     var alltagsid = new array '{tag_uid: + friend.id + ,x:20,y:20},'; 
       });
      } else {
          alert("Error!");
          }
     });
```